# How can I be certain that a user has verified their email after registration?

Tags: user-registration, email-verification

I'm working on a plugin that uses WordPress as the Single Sign On provider for another application. I need to be certain that the user has verified their email address by replying to the email sent out by `wp_new_user_notification()`.

So far the best approach I have found is to hook into the `after_password_reset` action and add user_metadata to indicate that the email is verified. This works, but all it's really telling me is that the `reset_password` function has been called.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Maybe `empty( get_userdata( $user_id )->user_activation_key )` ?

Comment: It looks like that is still just indicating that `reset_password` has been called.  (`reset_password` calls `wp_set_password`, that's where the activation key gets set to ''.)

Comment: What about a custom counter of password resets for each user, stored in the user meta ?

Answer (score 3):

I've tried a few different approaches for verifying the user's email. For now, what I am doing is this:

When a user first registers, set the user's user_metadata 'email_not_verified' to 1.

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'sc_user_email_not_verified' );
function sc_user_email_not_verified( $user_id ) {
  update_user_meta( $user_id, 'email_not_verified', 1 );
}
```

Then, override the `wp_new_user_notification` function so that it adds an 'email_verification_key' to the login url. It also saves that key as user_metadata.

```
function wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $depreciated = null, $notify = '' ) {

...

$email_verification_key = wp_generate_password( 20, false );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'email_verification_key', $email_verification_key );

$message = sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user->user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= __('To set your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&mail_key=$email_verification_key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n\r\n";
$message .= wp_login_url() . "\r\n";

wp_mail($user->user_email, sprintf(__('[%s] Your username and password info'), $blogname), $message);
}
```

Then, hook into the 'validate_password_reset' action to check that the email verification key from the password reset request matches the saved key. If the keys don't match, delete the user and redirect them back to the registration form with an error of 'emailnotverified'. If the keys do match, delete the 'email_not_verified' metadata.

```
add_action( 'validate_password_reset', 'sc_verify_user_email', 10, 2 );
function sc_verify_user_email( $errors, $user ) {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['mail_key'] ) ) {
        $email_verification_key = $_REQUEST['mail_key'];
        $saved_key              = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'email_verification_key', true );

        if ( ! ( $email_verification_key === $saved_key ) ) {
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/user.php' );
            wp_delete_user( $user->ID );
            wp_redirect( network_site_url( "wp-login.php?action=register&error=emailnotverified" ) );
            exit;
        } else {
            delete_user_meta( $user->ID, 'email_not_verified' );
        }
    }
}
```

If the email is not verified, add a message that will be displayed on the registration page when there is an 'emailnotverified' error.

```
add_filter( 'login_message', 'sc_email_not_verified_message' );
function sc_email_not_verified_message() {
    $action = isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';
    $error = isset( $_REQUEST['error'] ) ? $_REQUEST['error'] : '';

    if ( 'register' === $action && 'emailnotverified' === $error ) {
        $message = '<p class="message">' . __( 'Your email address could not be verified. Please try registering again.' ) . '</p>';
        return $message;
    }
}
```

Inside of the Single Sign On function, if the user has the 'email_not_verified' metadata, don't log them in to the client application. (This could happen if the user was created through a registration form that was added by a plugin.)

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'email_not_verified', true ) ) {
    echo( 'Invalid request.' ); // This needs to be changed to a redirect.
    exit;
}
```

I've also added a checkbox to display and override the user's email verification status on the 'user-edit' page.

---

Edit:

Hooking into the `validate_password_reset` action is probably not the best way to do this. It is called before the password is reset, so the email will be verified even if there are errors in the password reset process (for example if the key is expired or invalid.)

A better approach seems to be to hook into the `resetpass_form` action and add a hidden field to the password reset form that holds the value of the 'mail_key':

```
add_action( 'resetpass_form' 'sc_mail_key_field' );
function sc_mail_key_field() {

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['mail_key'] ) ) { 

        $mail_key = sanitize_key( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['mail_key'] ) );
        wp_nonce_field( 'verify_email', 'verify_email_nonce' );
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="mail_key" value="' . esc_attr( $mail_key ) . '" />';
    }
}
```

It is then possible to hook into the `after_password_reset` action to verify the saved mail key against the `$_POST['mail_key']` value.

An example plugin can be found here: [email address verification plugin](https://github.com/scossar/wordpress-email-verification)

Comment: Thanks for sharing what worked for you. PS: I would suggest prefixing custom meta data to avoid possible name collision with other plugins and  it's recommended to add `exit;` after `wp_redirect()`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the code on here to add `exit;` after `wp_redirect()`. In the code I am actually using, I am no longer deleting a user if their 'mail_key' doesn't match the saved key. Instead, if the keys don't match, the user is created, but with the 'email_not_verified' flag in place.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look into the `wp_usermeta` table and noticed the `default_password_nag` meta key.

I checked and this was introduced in [#9710](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9710) about 7 years ago.

If the user has an *auto generated password* then it's value is 1 and she will get a notice displayed on the dashboard screen.

When she first registers, `default_password_nag` is 1 and when she resets the password, following the email link, it becomes 0.

You can look further into this, if it can be of any use in your setup.

Otherwise one could create a custom *counter* or *flag* and store it in the *user meta*. E.g. hook into the user creation process and then update it when the user resets the password or logs in.

Comment: The problem is that it's possible for a plugin to allow the password to be reset without having the user respond to an email to reset it. WooCommerce does this if you select 'enable registration.' Possibly, it might be good enough to know that the password was reset _and_ that the resetting was handled by `wp-login.php`.

Comment: yes you're correct, plugins could affect the state of it, e.g. through custom login/reset forms. Most likely a custom counter/flag might be better in that case. The extreme case would be a plugin with user creation and password resets through custom SQL queries ;-)  @SimonCossar